# FCOE on CentOS 6.5. port state offline

Tags: centos6.5, netapp, fcoe

I am a network engg, and this is the first time I am trying to get FCOE working.

Here is my setup:

Centos server --------- transit switch ---- FC gateway ---- FC switch --- Netapp

I believe the configurations on my networking part is correct.

I am seeing FIP sessions to be up between the Centos server and the transit switch. The FC gateway is learning the WWN address.

However, I am not able to get the Centos server to talk to the Netapp appliance.
I believe the issue maybe due to the port state being offline:

[root@centos]# fcoeadm -i

```
Description:      BCM57840 NetXtreme II 10/20-Gigabit Ethernet
Revision:         11
Manufacturer:     Broadcom Corporation
Serial Number:    D87226A9D6C0
Driver:           bnx2x 1.78.17-0
Number of Ports:  1

    Symbolic Name:     bnx2fc (Broadcom BCM57840) v2.4.1 over eth4.40-fcoe
    OS Device Name:    host1
    Node Name:         0x1000D72289D66AC1
    Port Name:         0x2000D72289D66AC1
    FabricName:        0x0000000000000000
    Speed:             10 Gbit
    Supported Speed:   1 Gbit, 10 Gbit
    MaxFrameSize:      2048
    FC-ID (Port ID):   0x000000
    State:             Offline
```

Any suggestions on how to get this port be online? I think once this is done, I should see my server talk to the netapp appliance.

Comment: What model of NetApp do you have? What version of DataONTAP is installed on it?
Did you install NetApp Linux Host Utilities on host?
What models of switches and gateway do you use?

Comment: Check if the CNA adapter supports the feature of FCOE ..